# Android Development Latest Techniques

Tags: android

I am developing an android app, that perform CRUD operations and notify users. I am using following:

**IDE:** android studio
**Database:** Realm 
**Push Notification:** FCM
**Support multiple devices images:** drawable importer android studio plugin 
**Tab View:** Fragments
**Other activities:** Simple linear or relative layouts with back-end java file for each activity.

I'm not sure if I am on right track or not. As there would be wide use of application. I want to know if there is anything else that I'm not aware of and can use for better and easy development.

Comment: The question though is not related to a programming level issue still I would recommend to refine your search to read about best practices during development of specific task such as managing objects and classes.

Comment: You are on right track in choosing the techniques, but it is all about the coding structure that you develop, keep things generic considering the future scope of your app. Give vector-drawables a try as well for better icons quality and keeping apk size smaller

Comment: Your question is opinion-based. There is no correct answer to it.

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture